# Can I use Google Chrome without being signed in?

Tags: google-chrome

Whenever I try using Chrome, I get a message saying "Not signed in to Chrome".

Is it necessary to have a user profile in order to use Chrome?

Comment: Why not just ignore it?

Answer (score 15):

### Yes you can.

`chrome://settings/people`


[image: chrome://settings/people]


And then select `Sync And Google Services`

Turn off `Allow Chrome sign-in`

[image: new allow chrome sign in location]

Currently you can also jump directly to `chrome://settings/syncSetup`

Current as of `Version 99.0.4844.74 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

---

##### For older versions of chrome, view prior answer text:

But [starting with version 70][1], if you logged into any google service (e.g. gmail) via the Chrome browser, it will automatically sign you into the google accounts for chrome browser also.  But there is a way around this:

1. Navigate to `chrome://settings/privacy` (Privacy and Security sub menu under Advanced settings)
2. and turn **off**

```
Allow Chrome sign-in
By turning this off, you can sign in to Google sites like Gmail without signing in to Chrome
```

3. You will be prompted to relaunch the browser for the settings to take place.

This screenshot of `Version 77.0.3865.75 (Official Build) (64-bit)` will help.

[image: Disable forced login to chrome browser]

Comment: That fix doesn't last. Google will have that person signed in again before they realized what hit them.

Comment: I don't use Chrome much ([Brave](https://brave.com/) is the new daily driver, with [Waterfox](https://www.waterfox.net/) as mozilla alternate) But the last time I used it, there is no auto-login to google services for the browser.  Sessions are still saved via cookies. 
 But I would use another Chrome-based browser if google cannot be fully trusted to behave themselves. @NothingToSeeHere

Comment: also to add:  If you login to a google service ,then the `cookies` for that login session will be saved.  But that would be any browser that allows `cookies` to be saved (which is every browser). This is not the same as the `browser itself` being logged into google.  To get around this, all you have to do is either use a `Private/Incognito` browser window OR `clear cookies` on exiting the browser.  And also do not save that computer as a trusted computer in google accounts.  Which forces you to login each time a session expires. 
 @NothingToSeeHere

Answer (score 5):

Yes and no. There's a local user profile which stores your bookmarks, cookies and other preferences, and you need this to be able to access them. The Google login lets you sync these things between systems and is optional, but google tends to nag you about it. Logging out has no effect outside disabling sync.

You can create new users without linking them to a Google account, I believe, or just not sign in at all if you mean the Google login.

If you *totally* do not want to use a profile, I guess Incognito mode is the closest thing to that. You'd probably need to use this all the time though.

Answer (score 2):

Updated answer since Chrome v69 (when they automatically logged you into Chrome if you logged into gmail):

Set `chrome://flags/#account-consistency` to `Disabled`.

Then you will be able to login to gmail without being logged into Chrome.

https://www.theverge.com/2018/9/26/17904762/google-chrome-sign-in-changes-feedback

Comment: 2021: this flag no longer exists

Answer (score 2):

@Jon 's answer is correct, but on newer Chrome versions, the option is `chrome://settings/people` under **Sync and Google services**

Here are some Screenshots with freehand circles:
[image: You and Google]
[image: Sync and Google services]

Comment: To add to your answer: you will need to relaunch chrome for this take effect. When you change that setting, there is a prompt at the bottom left (for mac) to relaunch the chrome.

Answer (score 1):

There is a "No Thanks" link under the sign-in form. This will stop it from asking whenever Chrome starts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use Chrome without signing in. The only problem, though, would be that whenever you open Chrome, you won't be taken to your homepage. You will be taken to the Chrome Sign-In page every time!

Comment: not true.   Without logging into the browser, chrome (and brave, firefox, etc) can still save cookies so that it can save gmail and other google services login.   The browser and google desiring to track everything the browser user is doing is 2 separate functions.

Answer (score -2):

No but you are missing a better experience, if you have multiple computers you can not only share bookmarks but also tabs open.  On my Android phone I can open pages I left open on my home computer.

Answer (score -2):

**Yes you can use chrome without logging in**, but if you log in you can sync all your browser history, bookmarks, and cookies. so when you use another system or mobile device , log in with  the same account, you will get all your personal data back, that browser will behave like your home system browser. [Reason why you should sign in](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=165139)

Comment: This didn't answer the question.   And if the user wants to sync his/her browser history et al with google, they can temporarily login, perform sync, and then remove the login.